# Optimizing eval in pandas df.loc to count n of rows from multiple queries, multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, big-o, google-colaboratory

I have a pandas dataframe example with some car troubles

```
VinNumber   Date        Time        Repair Type  Garage Type    Indicator Noise      Dashboard   Condition
JMFE88888   2019-05-15  11:09:00    CONVENTIONAL    3   MECH    BATT      BUZZ       DIMMING     POOR IDLING    
JMFE99999   2019-05-15  15:43:00    CONVENTIONAL    3   MECH    CHK ENG   SPUTTERING N/A         LOSS OF POWER
```

I have grouped the criteria for a specific car trouble into a dictionary like this:

```
ALTERNATOR = {'Indicator': ('ALT','BATT'),
              'Noise': ('RATTLE','BUZZ'),
              'Dashboard': ('FLICKERING','DIMMING'),
              'Condition': ('RUNS BAD','WILL NOT START')}
```

where every column name contains a tuple with the values required in every column to meet the dictionary's condition/criteria.

So in order for a row to count as alternator trouble it would have to have either 'ALT' or 'BATT in the Indicator column, 'RATTLE' or 'BUZZ' in the Noise column and etc. etc.

I then make a bunch of other dictionaries like ALTERNATOR but for different defects and I put the string names of the dictionaries in a list.

```
DEFECTS = ['ALTERNATOR', 'TRANSMISSION', 'ENGINE', 'FUEL_PUMP', 'AC_HEAT', 'RADIO', ... ...]
```

So if I were to type

```
eval('ALTERNATOR')
```

I would get the actual dictionary with its contents printed.

Finally, I create a dictionary where I am to save the amount of specific defects each car has (INTerior or MECHanical).

```
car_defects = {car: {'INT': {'AC_HEAT': 0, 'RADIO': 0,
                                   'UPHOLSTERY': 0, 'AIRBAGS': 0},
                             'MECH': {'ALTERNATOR': 0, 'TRANSMISSION': 0,
                                   'ENGINE': 0, 'FUEL_PUMP': 0}} for car in df['VinNumber'].unique()}
```

And in that dictionary each car will have its own count of specific defects that I get using the following code:

```
for c in df['VinNumber'].unique(): # for every unique car in the dataframe
  for p in ['INT', 'MECH']: # Interior or Mechanical
    for defect in DEFECTS:
      car_defects[c][p][defect] = df.loc[(df['VinNumber'] == c) &
                                         (df['Type'].str[1] == p) & (df['Indicator'].isin(eval(defect)['Indicator'])) &
                                         (df['Noise'].isin(eval(defect)['Noise'])) &
                                         (df['Dashboard'].isin(eval(defect)['Dashboard'])) &
                                         (df['Condition'].isin(eval(defect)['Condition']))]['VinNumber'].count()
```

So for every defect in both MECH and INT and for every single unique VinNumber in the dataframe, the code looks at how many rows can be counted as an instance of that defect and assigns the count of those rows to the value stored at that defect, at that location (p), at that specific VinNumber (c).

The code works, but on a 11k rows dataframe with 478 unique values in the VinNumber column it is extremely slow. I suspected the nested loops were the sole reason for the slowdown, but I tried the example below without the eval or df.loc portions and the dict value assignment was extremely fast even on bigger dictionaries. This leads me to believe that either eval or df.loc are responsible for the slowdown, is there any way to optimize this code and make it run faster?

```
food = {n: {1: {'rice': 0, 'beans': 0, 'noodles': 0, 'eggs': 0, 'flour': 0, 'cheese': 0, 'poultry': 0, 'beef': 0, 'fruits': 0, 'veggies': 0},
            2: {'rice': 0, 'beans': 0, 'noodles': 0, 'eggs': 0, 'flour': 0, 'cheese': 0, 'poultry': 0, 'beef': 0, 'fruits': 0, 'veggies': 0}} for n in range(0, 3500)}


for n in range(0, 3500):
   for i in [1, 2]:
      for foo in ['rice', 'beans', 'noodles', 'eggs', 'flour', 'cheese', 'poultry', 'beef','fruits', 'veggies']:
...      food[n][i][foo] = 9001
```